# fit jtable into the whole internal frame

Tags: java, swing

I want to create an internal frame with the table, that fully occupies it - like no matter how many rows or columns it should occupy all frame. I do it like this

```
    JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame();
    internalFrame.setSize(600, 400);
    internalFrame.setVisible(true);
    internalFrame.setClosable(true);
    internalFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    JTable table = new JTable(generateEmptyData(),
        new Object[] { "Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3", "Line 4", "Line 5" });
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    internalFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    internalFrame.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

But it looks like this

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: What do you expect to happen. I see a table with 5 columns and 5 rows.  The columns fill the space available The rows are painted at the default height. The only change you need is to use: `internalFrame.add( new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER );` Now you will see your columns headings. That is you must add the table to a scroll pane and the scroll pane to the frame in order for the headings to appear.

Comment: I wanted bigger cells so that 5 rows and 5 columns would fill the whole frame

Comment: I already explained the columns DO fill the frame. The rows do NOT automatically resize. You can use the `setRowHeight(...)` method of the `JTable` to adjust the default size if your wish. If you want a "grid" that automatically resizes, use a JPanel with a GridLayout and add labels to each grid.

Comment: @camickr so basically you suggest to use grid layout, set it to colors similar to the table and that's it? Oh. Row height.